# /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, nokogiri, macports

having this problem on installing several things on my mac,
i think this problem is coming from upgrading my leopard to snow leopard. Also this problem also is linked with macports i think.

```
/usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

To be more specific this happens on installing nokogiri gem

and the log looks like:

```
xslt_stylesheet.c:127: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Nokogiri_wrap_xml_document’ with different width due to prototype
cc -dynamic -bundle -undefined suppress -flat_namespace -o nokogiri.bundle     
html_document.o html_element_description.o html_entity_lookup.o   html_sax_parser_context.o nokogiri.o xml_attr.o xml_attribute_decl.o xml_cdata.o xml_comment.o xml_document.o xml_document_fragment.o xml_dtd.o xml_element_content.o xml_element_decl.o xml_encoding_handler.o xml_entity_decl.o xml_entity_reference.o xml_io.o xml_libxml2_hacks.o xml_namespace.o xml_node.o xml_node_set.o xml_processing_instruction.o xml_reader.o xml_relax_ng.o xml_sax_parser.o xml_sax_parser_context.o xml_sax_push_parser.o xml_schema.o xml_syntax_error.o xml_text.o xml_xpath_context.o xslt_stylesheet.o -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.     -lruby -lexslt -lxslt -lxml2  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc   
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nokogiri.bundle] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a macport migration to snow leopard issue, sadly you have to reinstall macports and all the ports to have the right architecture. Read the wiki here: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

Comment: oh my bad... i've read /opt/local instead of /usr/local. I seems that you have a custom zlib in /usr/local. You have two options: 1.figure out why you need a custom zlib with an i386 arch and if you don't remove it. 2. try to tweak your CFLAGS/LD_LIBRARY_PATH env to hide /usr/local from the compiler

Comment: I think i have it from the old os(leopard) probably used by imagemagick. At step 2 can you provide information how to do it?,thanks

Comment: it's not a step it's another option. Personaly i would stick with 1. and remove libz from /usr/local as you are now running on x86_64 (It would make sense to recompile imagemagick and libz to be now on this architecture)

Comment: removing the file solved my problem, i have a lot of problems from this architectural change when I try to install something, also installed rails 3 and now everything is a complete mess, if one thing works the other dont.i only can install gems with sudo and puts all my gems to usr/local/lib/ruby/gems. This thing drives me crazy. Anyway i accept your solution because worked, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is actually no way to hide /usr/local from the compiler. You have to move it away to avoid such problems while building software. `sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local-off`

Answer (score 15):

This is not about MacPorts:
zlib is installed as i386, so you have to build it for x86-64. Here's how to do it:

1. **Update**: As Nick says in his comment, you first have to remove old zlib files: `sudo rm /opt/local/lib/libz*`
2. Download zlib source code from [its webpage](http://zlib.net)
3. Extract the source, and open a terminal in source location
4. `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`
5. If it still doesn't work, remove ruby and install it again (you can do it with [RVM](https://rvm.io))

Hope it helped you.

Comment: This worked great for me.  I'm using RVM and did not have to change anything about my RVM/Ruby installations.  Simply removing the old zlib files and reinstalling is all it took. `sudo rm /opt/local/lib/libz*`.  (Simply installing the new version was not enough to remove these old files.)

Comment: Perfect! Another happy Googler. <3

Comment: I honestly thought I was going crazy on this one.  This was quite useful.  Thank you Nick/Carlos

Answer (score 1):

- You might have x86_64 compiled zlib installed in
     `/usr/local/opt/zlib/` or alternatively do a `brew install zlib`
     this will install zlib in `/usr/local/Cellar/`.
- Temporary remove `libz.*` from `/usr/local/lib/` into a backup folder.
- Do `gem install nokogiri -v '<version>' --with-zlib-dir=<zlib directory path from step 1>`

Nokogiri must be installed by now. Restore the backup libz again.